# How to decode uniswap v3 Router 2 transaction

Tags: transactions, uniswap, parser

I am trying to parse uniswap transaction and extract "summary" like what Etherscan does when showing transaction ([like this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd72a4edd39a45a65055a7b9b8a1c772c21012801be195ef529f2f96bdbbdf6a8)) below:

```
Transaction Action:
Swap 2,937.943845 USDC For 1.055626826417338071 Ether On Uniswap V3
Swap 1.055626826417338071 Ether For 73.765903190964302924 TORN On Uniswap V3
```

The raw transaction data looks like this:

```
{
    "blockHash": "0x4de7a163e436e0085772da19f837e3cd7ac4c976f0acefcf41195a5262d004ee",
    "blockNumber": 14237558,
    "from": "0xd26BaA5F41CC7839CEdb020b6d98E1C6e1642D75",
    "gas": 272371,
    "gasPrice": "61850376427",
    "maxFeePerGas": "79333124379",
    "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "1500000000",
    "hash": "0xd72a4edd39a45a65055a7b9b8a1c772c21012801be195ef529f2f96bdbbdf6a8",
    "input": "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",
    "nonce": 53,
    "to": "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45",
    "transactionIndex": 44,
    "value": "0",
    "type": 2,
    "accessList":
    [],
    "chainId": "0x1",
    "v": "0x0",
    "r": "0x3a00df8025b591167bf0f05fce01a84e79260dea7d5d3720a2a6d795383f1fe4",
    "s": "0x6db1374f2058e222b73419dd9b3974dad1d6c9d5478dc9ac09a9f2943a0947a3"
}
```

I am assuming that the transaction summary can be extracted from the `input` attribute, but unsure how to do that.

Comment: You have to analyze the log entries in the transaction's receipt.

Answer (score 4):

After some more digging, I found out [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/decoding-ethereum-smart-contract-data-eed513a65f76), which explained how to get some data out of the `input` attribute of the transaction (no transaction logs required). See below the function that takes a transaction hash and outputs `from` and `to` tokens (other data is also available in the input). Note, that `amountOutMin` doesn't give you exact data about how much token will be received, but it was enough in my case.

I use [abi-decoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abi-decoder) library to decode input data. ABI itself is downloaded from [ethernet GetABI API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts).

Also, `getTokenSymbol` function in the code just calls .symbol() API of the ERC20 contract to get token symbol.

```
async function processTransaction(transactionHash) {
  let transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);

  const data = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(transaction.input);
  const paths = data.params.filter((param) => param.name === "path")[0].value;
  const fromToken = paths[0];
  const toToken = paths.slice(-1)[0];
  const amountIn = data.params.filter((param) => param.name === "amountIn")[0]
    .value;
  const amountOutMin = data.params.filter(
    (param) => param.name === "amountOutMin"
  )[0].value;
  const fromTokenSymbol = await getTokenSymbol(fromToken);
  const toTokenSymbol = await getTokenSymbol(toToken);
  console.log(
    `Exchanged ${amountIn} of ${fromTokenSymbol} to at least ${amountOutMin} ${toTokenSymbol}`
  );
}
```